# Having trouble getting hired on Upwork, how can I get hired?

Tags: freelance-websites, project-bidding

So basically my cover goes like this:

> Hello Sir or Madam,
>
> I am writing in response to your advertisement for someone who can organize and transfer data's. After carefully reviewing the experience requirements of the job description, I feel that I am a suitable match for the job.
>
> I’ve held several data entry positions that entail inputting customer requests, inquire, and tracking codes of products I also perform administrative duties including answering telephones, transferring data, web research and reports to immediate supervisor.
>
> I feel that I can add professionalism and accuracy to your current team of professionals. With extensive experience supporting all levels of a department and working directly with external vendors, I take direction well and can complete a heavy workload and complete projects under minimal supervision. If you feel there is a mutual interest, I would welcome the opportunity to meet with you to learn more about your company, the requirements of the position,and how my qualifications would be a good fit.
>
> It would be my pleasure to work with you in the earliest time possible!
> Thank you in advance for your time and consideration.
> I look forward to Hiring from you soon.
>
> Devoughn M. Querubin
> Skype:Devquerubin
>
> E-mail:Devoughn34@gmail.com

I don't have job experience, but I'm really willing to work! I'm willing to take any job at this point (although I am currently applying for data entry jobs), and I've completed three tests with an above-average score. I am so frustrated already!

How can I improve my Upwork account?

Additionally, in my profile, I don't have any job experiences (I only have 40% completeness of profile). Should I fake job experiences into my profile so that my profile will be 100% complete?

Comment: Data entry jobs receive 100+ applications. Upworn filters those who are more attractive to clients by putting them on top. You are obviously on the bottom among dozens of others. If you add 40% of filled profile, you seem to them like unserious contractor.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to address the BIG issue on this question first: **NEVER EVER** fake job experience. Why?

1. No one trusts people who lie
2. People will eventually find out, then question everything you do
3. Misrepresentation can get you sued (depending on what you said/claimed)
4. No trust - no work!

As for improving your account, you obviously need jobs. Do not put all your eggs in one basket (ie - don't just rely on Upwork for jobs). Look for community organizations you care about, and offer services at a reduce rate, in exchange for them giving you a testimonial or adding the project to your portfolio. This part breaks down to just getting yourself out there.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically with regard to your cover letter, it talks extensively about you and how you are a good fit. Sorry, but this is a no-no. Nobody cares. We've all heard the advice to tell your story and provide evidence that you are up to the task. But as someone who has hired off ODesk/Elance (prior to Upwork), that's all secondary.

First and foremost, I have a problem. That's why I'm looking for someone to hire. My goal is not hire the most experienced person or the person with most certification. My goal is to solve my problem, within the problem and time constraints I have. Experience and past roles are evidence that you are lower risk, but they do not indicate that you understand the problem I have, how to solve it, or that you have any interest in it.

Kill two birds with one stone: 1) write a better cover letter that 2) doesn't lie. Address the problem, ask questions about it, and explain how you're going to help the hiring manager solve their problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Fake experience will never lead you to success

In Upwork , It seems you are missing many other information to fill up because job experience and portfolio adds 20% to profile completeness , so if you fill other all information then your profile completeness should be at least 70%-80%.

**I would like to give you some suggestion to improve profile:**

1. Complete your profile with all true/real details
2. I hope you successfully pass upwork readiness test , if not then pass it first.
3. Make sure you have uploaded profile photo as per upwork rules.
4. Do not add extra skills to you profile , Select only those skills in which you are confident to complete work.
5. In your summary/about section , write descriptive about you and what you can do professionally.
6. Add portfolio if you have otherwise at start level it is fine.
7. In future , update your skills when you learn something new.

**Suggestions to get project :**

1. Find jobs for which you are confident to complete successfully.
2. Write always unique and job related cover letter
3. Never do copy/paste cover letter for all jobs you are going to apply.
4. Your cover letter should be 100% job specific.
5. If possible then write in cover letter that how you will complete that job , estimated hours you will take etc.
6. Never give over hours estimation , Be honest.
7. Do not share your email/skype with cover letter until and unless client asks.

I hope above things will help you to get projects on upwork.